# geom_tile : Clean Diagonal Tiles Border

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a heatmap created with `geom_tile` on which the x and y values are the same and ordered the same way.
I would like to put black borders around the tiles in the diagonal of the chart.

```
set.seed(42L)
data <- data.frame(x = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3L), 
                   y = rep(letters[1:3], 3L), 
                   fill = rnorm(9L))
```

My option is to use the `color` aes with a variable set to `TRUE` or `NA` and using `scale_color_manual` to remove the grey borders for `NA` values.

```
data$diag <- data$x == data$y
data$diag[!data$diag] <- NA

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fill)) +
  geom_tile(aes(color = diag), size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(guide = FALSE, values = c(`TRUE` = "black"))
```

[image]

But the render is not that clean, the border seems a bit overlayed by the "invisible" NA borders.

How can I improve my chart ? Is there another method to do it ?
Thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the borders are overlayed not by the "invisible" NA borders, which really don't exist, but rather by the tiles themselves. Meaning that we are dealing with the order of layers. What we can try then is first to add a plain `geom_tile` and then another `geom_tile` with borders using only the data for the diagonal tiles.  That is,

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fill)) + geom_tile() +
  geom_tile(data = data[!is.na(data$diag), ], aes(color = diag), size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(guide = FALSE, values = c(`TRUE` = "black"))
```

[image]

Your question relates to [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35346088/1320535), where all the tiles had a border and the goal was for them not to overlap. Then tile sizes can be adjusted as to create space for borders. In this case, however, by adjusting tile sizes we would create some gaps, which makes things look worse.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fill)) +
  geom_tile(aes(color = diag), width = 0.98, height = 0.98, size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(guide = FALSE, values = c(`TRUE` = "black"))
```

[image]

On the other hand, it agrees with the idea that there is no way to adjust the order of layers in the same single `geom_tile` call.

Lastly, another alternative inspired by @utubun's answer.

```
data$diag <- data$x == data$y
ggplot(data[order(data$diag), ], aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fill)) +
  geom_tile(aes(color = diag), size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(guide = FALSE, values = c(`TRUE` = "black", `FALSE` = NA))
```

In this case we sort the data inside the call, but also need to specify that `FALSE` borders should be invisible.

Comment: indeed it make more sense if it's overlayed by the tile itself, thank you, no way to do this in the same `geom_tile` function ?

Comment: @JulienNavarre, I don't think so, I added some comments on that.

Comment: @JulienNavarre, utubun's answer gives more insight into this overlapping issue: it's not only tiles on top of borders, but also later rows on top of earlier rows, so sorting the rows beforehand also provides a solution. Of course, instead of extra `geom_tile` then one still has to sort the data.

Answer (score 6):

You can reach the desired result without a second `geom_tile()` call by changing the ordering of the original data.frame (ensuring that the tiles with borders are drawn the last):

```
set.seed(42L)

dat <- data.frame(
    x    = rep(letters[1:3], each  = 3L), 
    y    = rep(letters[1:3], times = 3L), 
    fill = rnorm(9L)
  ) |>
  dplyr::mutate(isdiag = (x == y)) |>
  dplyr::arrange(isdiag)

  ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fill)) +
      geom_tile(size = 2, colour = dat$isdiag) +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(axis.title = element_blank())
```

[image: tiles]